# Флешка не устанавливает драйвера на Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, драйвер, ос

Купил флешку в 2010 году. Воткнул её в USB-порт компьютера на котором стоит Windows 10.
Меня удивило, что флешка не устанавливала свои драйвера... как это бывает на Windows 7, 8, Vista... и сразу открыла проводник..

Вопрос... значит флешки не устанавливают драйвера свои где стоит Win10?
Правильно ли я всё понял?

Comment: Это функция называется "автозапуск" и настраивается для многих подключаемых устройств (флешки, карты памяти, телефоны, диски). Меню автозапуск можно найти на панели управления в устройствах. Грубо говоря Windows умеет по умолчанию запускать программы со съемных носителей без прямого указания пользователя. Могу ошибаться, но вроде для Windows 7 он тоже по умолчанию отключен.

Comment: @Alex Krass, Купил в магазине флешку сто лет назад... 2010 году.
Вставил в USB порт где стоит Windows 7, сразу возле часов появилось сообщение, что устанавливается драйвер флешки... потом после установки открылся проводник. Потом эту флешку вставил в USB-порт компьтера с Windows 10. Но к моему удивлению сразу открылся проводник. Драйвер не устанавливался как с Windows 7.
Почему так? Значит ли, что флешку уже туда тыркали?

Comment: В Windows 7 и 10 есть драйвер по умолчанию для таких устройств и его активация занимает какое-то время. Возможно в Win10 они просто усовершенствовали этот механизм и он работает достаточно быстро, что-то они там переделывали в этом плане. Но точно не могу сказать, не разбирался с этим вопросом.